# Only two master nodes are up in Kubernetes cluster with kops in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, cassandra, kops, kubernetes-cluster

I am trying to setup kubernetes cluster in AWS using KOPS. I configured for 3 master nodes and 6 nodes. But after launching the cluster only two master nodes are up.

I am using `.k8s.local` DNS instead of Purchased DNS. Below is the script that I am using for creating the cluster.

```
kops create cluster \
--cloud=aws \
--name=kops-cassandra-cluster-01.k8s.local \
--zones=ap-south-1a,ap-south-1b,ap-south-1c \
--master-size="t2.small" \
--master-count 3 \
--master-zones=ap-south-1a,ap-south-1b,ap-south-1c \
--node-size="t2.small" \
--ssh-public-key="kops-cassandra-cluster-01.pub" \
--state=s3://kops-cassandra-cluster-01 \
--node-count=6
```

After executing `kops update cluster --name=kops-cassandra-cluster-01.k8s.local --state=s3://kops-cassandra-cluster-01 --yes` 
only two master nodes are available instead of 3.

`kubectl get nodes` shows:

```
NAME                                           STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
ip-172-20-44-37.ap-south-1.compute.internal    Ready    master   18m   v1.12.8
ip-172-20-52-78.ap-south-1.compute.internal    Ready    node     18m   v1.12.8
ip-172-20-60-234.ap-south-1.compute.internal   Ready    node     18m   v1.12.8
ip-172-20-61-141.ap-south-1.compute.internal   Ready    node     18m   v1.12.8
ip-172-20-66-215.ap-south-1.compute.internal   Ready    node     18m   v1.12.8
ip-172-20-69-124.ap-south-1.compute.internal   Ready    master   18m   v1.12.8
ip-172-20-85-58.ap-south-1.compute.internal    Ready    node     18m   v1.12.8
ip-172-20-90-119.ap-south-1.compute.internal   Ready    node     18m   v1.12.8
```

I am new to Kubernetes. Am I missing something?

Comment: what `kubectl get nodes` shows? paste its output in question.

Comment: Have you checked on AWS whether that 3rd master node is actually started and running?

Comment: I checked but 3rd master is not created at all. And I noticed there is no nodes created in AZ ap-south-1c. All the nodes including worker nodes are in AZ ap-south-1a and ap-south-1b.

Comment: Hve you checked kops logs. lso try to run kops commands in verbose mode `-v` option. Check this https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/cli/kops.md for more info around log options.

Answer (score 1):

After doing a lot of research I came to know that it is because of t2.small instance type is not available in ap-south-1c. After modifying the zones to eu-west-1a,eu-west-1b,eu-west-1c, I can see 3 master nodes and 6 worker nodes. Thanks @mchawre for your help.